# Verb to replace "set bounds"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, verbs, programming

I'm developing some GUI software and I want to mean that this widget bounds/edges are attached to some `boundary` structure, something like:

`bounds = { .left = 0, .top = 0, .right: 320, .bottom: 240 };
widget.set_bounds(bounds);`

I want to avoid the `set` word. I have thought of `widget.bind` but I'm almost sure it doesn't mean the same.

Is there a verb that means what I want?

Thanks in advance.

### *EDIT*

While looking at a dictionary, I've seen that `bound` can actually be used as a verb, although I haven't seen it being used like that.

`widget.bound(bounds)`

Would this be readable enough or even correct?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the word 'set'? It's a pretty good word to describe what you are doing with the bounds, and is widely understood in software circles. It also has plenty of synonyms - prescribe, define, specify, assign, designate, ordain,...

Comment: To set bounds is to delimit, isn't it?

Comment: Partition should work...

Comment: You could replace *set* with *have*

Comment: @DJClayworth its just personal preference, I tend to avoid set/get methods. Widget doesn't have an internal 'bounds' field, so technically I'm not setting it, I'm making the widget use those bounds to set its size.

Answer (score 1):

The word "Border" can be used as a verb here.

Germany *borders* Italy up in the mountains. Spain *borders* Portugal as well.

I can't say it would be an appealing use of the word, though.

Meet or meets might be another possibility. Your edges *meet* the boundaries you have set.

Comment: Not sure that bounds and boundaries work the same way in terms of referents.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want to avoid the word set, but if you really don't want to use "set", then I can suggest:

widget.resizeBounds(bounds)
widget.resizeBoundsTo(bounds)
widget.resizeExtentsTo(bounds)
widget.resizeDimensTo(bounds)
widget.fitBoundsTo(bounds)
widget.resizeToFit(bounds)

Comment: I'm personally against sets and gets in my code, I feel they lack what the method is actually doing, but that's a philosophical and endless discussion.